# Confused about merge sort implementation

Tags: scala

What is occurring on this line, `x` is being concatenated to `xs1` but `x` and `xs1` are not defined anywhere?

```
case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) =>
```

Also here, what value do have `x` and `y` below? Is merge being recursively called as part of the case class?

```
if( x < y) x :: merge(xs1 , ys)
```

Here is the complete Scala code :

```
object mergesort {

    def msort(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
        val n = xs.length / 2
        if(n == 0) xs
        else {
            def merge(xs: List[Int], ys: List[Int]): List[Int] = (xs , ys) match {
            case (Nil, ys) => ys
            case (xs, Nil) => xs
            case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) =>
                if( x < y) x :: merge(xs1 , ys)
                else y :: merge(xs, ys1)
            }


        val (fst, snd) = xs splitAt n
        merge(msort(fst), msort(snd))
        }
    }                                         //> msort: (xs: List[Int])List[Int]

    val nums = List(2, -4, 5, 7, 1)           //> nums  : List[Int] = List(2, -4, 5, 7, 1)
    msort(nums)                               //> res0: List[Int] = List(-4, 1, 2, 5, 7)

}
```

Comment: See: http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/pattern_matching.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how scala allows you to do pattern matching on a List:

```
scala> List(1,2,3)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> res0 match {
     | case h :: t => "more than two elements, " + h + " is the first"
     | case _ => "less than two elements"
     | }
res1: java.lang.String = more than two elements, 1 is the first
```

Note that `::` on the left side of the `case` decomposes the list in its head ( `1` ) and its tail (the rest of the list `2, 3`) and binds the values to `h` and `t`, that are created and scoped only inside the first `case`.

Here's how you decompose a tuple:

```
scala> val tp = ("a", 1)
tp: (java.lang.String, Int) = (a,1)

scala> tp match {
     | case (a, b) => a + " is a string, " + b + " is a number"
     | case _ => "something missing"
     | }
res2: java.lang.String = a is a string, 1 is a number
```

In the code in your question you're mixing both things and pattern matching on a tuple of Lists `(xs , ys)`.

`case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1)` is both decomposing the tuple in its two lists and  decomposing its two lists in their respective heads and tails.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) =>
```

`::` is a syntactic sugar in pattern matching to de-construct a `list` in to `head` and `tail`

the list `xs` is de-constructed in to head `x` and tail `xs`.

In pattern matching `::` de-constructs' a list, exact reverse of what it actually does in normal, `construct` a list.

Read De-Constructing objects in [The Point of Pattern Matching in Scala](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/pattern_matching.html)

Answer (score 1):

This

```
(xs , ys) match {
     ...     
    case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1)
```

is a *pattern match* that declares the variables `x`, `xs1` etc. in the same statement as asserting a sequence match.

The code above is checking that xs can be decomposed into a sequence with head `x` and tail `xs1`, and if so, making the head/tail available to the successive code block in those two variables.

To answer your second question (since nobody else has!), yes, the `merge` function (declared within the outer function) is being called recursively.

Answer (score 0):

The match-case keywords are used in scala to perform pattern matching, which is a way to match/decompose objects using several mechanisms like case classes and extractors. Google for scala pattern matching and you'll find the answers you need.